# Display Search Bar in Navigation Bar IOS7

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uisearchbar

I would like to ask on how to display a search bar in navigation bar when I tapped the Search Icon in IOS 7, almost all of the tutorial that I browse is not supporting IOS 7, maybe you can give an idea on how to implement that functionalities.

Here's the screenshot of our UI:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

**(1)** Add `UISearchBar` in your XIB at the top of the view having width equal to its parent view. Add required constraints.

[image]

**(2)** Set `IBOutlet` and assign delegate to that search bar.

**(3)** Implement following delegate methods:

```
# pragma mark
# pragma mark - SearchBar delegate

- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [searchBarWatches resignFirstResponder];
    searchBarWatches.text = @"";

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
        searchBarWatches.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [searchBarWatches setHidden:TRUE];
        searchBarWatches.alpha = 1.0;
    }];    
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    // searchBarTextDidBeginEditing
}

- (void)searchBarTextDidEndEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    strSearchText = @"";
    [self searchWatchWithString:strSearchText];
}

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    searchText = [searchText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                  [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    if([searchText isEqualToString:strSearchText]) {
        return;
    }

    if([searchText length] > 0) {
        strSearchText = searchText;
    } else {
        strSearchText = @"";
    }

    [self searchWatchWithString:strSearchText];
}

-(void)searchWatchWithString:(NSString *)strSearch
{
    if([strSearch length] > 0)
    {
        NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:....];
        NSPredicate *predicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:....];
        NSPredicate *predicate3 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:....];
        NSPredicate *predicate  = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicate1, predicate2, predicate3]];
        [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    else
    {
        // Empty string
    }

    [self performFetch];
    [self reloadTableViewAnimated:TRUE];
} 

-(void)reloadTableViewAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(animated) {
        [tblProducts reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0]];
    } else {
        [tblProducts reloadData];
    }
}
```

**(4)** On click of search button, show search bar:

```
- (IBAction)btnSearchPressed:(id)sender
{
    [searchBarWatches setHidden:FALSE];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:searchBarWatches]; 
    [searchBarWatches becomeFirstResponder];
}
```